# Ignore changes to m2m relationship in post_save signal of django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm, django-signals

I've got a question regarding django signals.

Let's say I have these models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_name = (...)

class Children(models.Model):
    child_name  = (...)
    parent      = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children')
```

And let's assume I have this signal connected to the `post_save` signal of `Parent` class:

```
def handle(*args, **kwargs):
   (...)

post_save.connect(handle, sender=Parent)
```

Now, If I create a new child:

```
some_parent = Parent.objects.get(...)
new_child = Child.objects.create(
    ...,
    parent = some_parent
)
```

Even though I'm just creating a new `Child`, Django will send a `post_save` signal from `some_parent` and thus `handle` will be invoked. Is there a way to ignore this signal? Something similar to this:

```
def handle(*args, **kwargs):
    if <some_condition>: # check if the signal is sent just because a new child is created
        # Ignore the signal
        return
    # Do everything as usual
    ...
```

Comment: I tried it out, and I never get the signal when creating the child. Only when explicitly calling `save` on parent. Are you sure there are no other methods calling save on the parent?

Comment: The code base is very large. I'm not sure. I'll check it out. Thank you for pointing out this tip.

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, the first args to the post_save handler are `instance` and `created`.

```py
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Parent)
def handle(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        return
    do_thingamy()
```